# Continue in try: except: seems not to skip code block

Tags: python, exception, continue

I am having difficulty using exception handling to create a custom formatted list of lists from a raw list of lists.  My code is as follows (sorry for the wall of code, most of it is just defining the lists involved):

```
def get_data():
    header_list = ['Gross profit', 'Research and development', 
                   'Total costs and expenses', 'Total operating expenses',
                   'Operating income', 'Income before income taxes']
    raw_financial_data = [['Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions'
                           ' except per share data.', 'TTM', '2012-12', 
                           '2011-12', '2010-12', '2009-12', '2008-12'], 
                          ['Gross profit', '125390', '146216', '179627', 
                           '120923', '98817', '188549'], ['Costs and expenses'],                         
                          ['Total costs and expenses', '64695', '67490',
                           '106370', '67964', '64040', '106799'],
                          ['Income before income taxes', '60695', '78726',
                           '73257', '52959', '34777', '81750']]
    financial_data = []
    rfd_header = [h[0] for h in raw_financial_data]            
    ttm_count = 0
    for d in header_list:                
        for i in raw_financial_data:
            try:
                if i[1] == 'TTM' and ttm_count == 0:
                    financial_data.append(i)
                    ttm_count = 1
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                continue   
            if i[0] == d:
                financial_data.append(i)
            elif d not in rfd_header:
                rfd_header.append(d)
                financial_data.append(['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A',
                                                'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A','N/A'])
    return financial_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for row in get_data():
        print row
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
['Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.', 'TTM', '2012-12', '2011-12', '2010-12', '2009-12', '2008-12']
['Gross profit', '125390', '146216', '179627', '120923', '98817', '188549']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['Total costs and expenses', '64695', '67490', '106370', '67964', '64040', '106799']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['Income before income taxes', '60695', '78726', '73257', '52959', '34777', '81750']
```

What I want to happen is for line 3 of the output above to be omitted from `financial_data`.   The rest of the 'No Data' rows are as expected, but I am not sure why the `except IndexError: continue` does not skip to the next `i` in `raw_financial_data` without appending a 'No Data' row, since an `IndexError` should be raised for the item `['Costs and expenses']` in `header_list`.

I am open to a better methodology to achieve this result if there is one, but I would like to understand why 'No Data' rows are appended in this code when I thought that the whole block with the `financial_data.append` was being skipped with a `continue` statement.

Comment: Please  post a **minimum** working example :-)

Comment: Fredrik Pihl: Done. Relevant bits can be seen without scrolling now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `continue` statement is working as you expect. The 3rd line - "No Data" is coming from a change in `d` to `Research and development`. I've added a few print statements to demonstrate:

```
def get_data():
    header_list = ['Gross profit', 'Research and development', 
                   'Total costs and expenses', 'Total operating expenses',
                   'Operating income', 'Income before income taxes']
    raw_financial_data = [['Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.', 'TTM', '2012-12', '2011-12', '2010-12', '2009-12', '2008-12'], 
                          ['Gross profit', '125390', '146216', '179627', '120923', '98817', '188549'], 
                          ['Costs and expenses'],                         
                          ['Total costs and expenses', '64695', '67490', '106370', '67964', '64040', '106799'],
                          ['Income before income taxes', '60695', '78726', '73257', '52959', '34777', '81750']]
    financial_data = []
    rfd_header = [h[0] for h in raw_financial_data]            
    ttm_count = 0
    for d in header_list:                
        print ''
        print d
        for i in raw_financial_data:
            try:
                if i[1] == 'TTM' and ttm_count == 0:
                    print '1st append', i
                    financial_data.append(i)
                    ttm_count = 1
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                print 'IndexError'
                continue   
            if i[0] == d:
                print '2nd append', i
                financial_data.append(i)
            elif d not in rfd_header:
                rfd_header.append(d)
                print '3nd append', 'No Data'
                financial_data.append(['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A',
                                                'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A','N/A'])
            else:
                print 'no append'
    return financial_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for row in get_data():
        print row
```

And here's the output:

```
Gross profit
1st append ['Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.', 'TTM', '2012-12', '2011-12', '2010-12', '2009-12', '2008-12']
2nd append ['Gross profit', '125390', '146216', '179627', '120923', '98817', '188549']
IndexError
no append
no append

Research and development
3nd append No Data
no append
IndexError
no append
no append

Total costs and expenses
no append
no append
IndexError
2nd append ['Total costs and expenses', '64695', '67490', '106370', '67964', '64040', '106799']
no append

Total operating expenses
3nd append No Data
no append
IndexError
no append
no append

Operating income
3nd append No Data
no append
IndexError
no append
no append

Income before income taxes
no append
no append
IndexError
no append
2nd append ['Income before income taxes', '60695', '78726', '73257', '52959', '34777', '81750']
['Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.', 'TTM', '2012-12', '2011-12', '2010-12', '2009-12', '2008-12']
['Gross profit', '125390', '146216', '179627', '120923', '98817', '188549']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['Total costs and expenses', '64695', '67490', '106370', '67964', '64040', '106799']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['No Data', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['Income before income taxes', '60695', '78726', '73257', '52959', '34777', '81750']
```

Comment: Peter, I had been staring at this code in-situ too long, with preconceived notions of what the output should be.  Thanks for helping me see what my own code is *actually* doing instead of what I think it should be doing.

Comment: @dman no problem, happens all the time. You should take a run through the code with `pdb` (the python debugger) you'd spot the problem in an instant. Although I think there's something to be said for not resorting straight to a debugger to understand your code too.